# How to write unit test for a program that contains channels, filewalk and api call in golang?

Tags: unit-testing, go

My program is as follows as a whole.

```
func main() {

    flag.Parse()

    if *token == "" {
        log.Fatal(Red + "please provide a client token => -token={$token}")
    }

    tokenSource := oauth2.StaticTokenSource(&oauth2.Token{AccessToken: *token})
    oauthClient := oauth2.NewClient(context.TODO(), tokenSource)
    client := putio.NewClient(oauthClient)

    //paths := make(chan string)
    var wg = new(sync.WaitGroup)
    for i := 0; i < 50; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go worker(paths, wg, client)
    }
    WalkFilePath()
    //if err := filepath.Walk(*rootpath, func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
    //  if err != nil {
    //      return fmt.Errorf("Failed to walk directory: %T %w", err, err)
    //  }
    //  if !info.IsDir() {
    //      paths <- path
    //  }
    //  return nil
    //}); err != nil {
    //  panic(fmt.Errorf("failed Walk: %w", err))
    //}
    close(paths)
    wg.Wait()
}

// walks the file path and sends paths to channel
func WalkFilePath() {
    if err := filepath.Walk(*rootpath, func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if err != nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("Failed to walk directory: %T %w", err, err)
        }
        if !info.IsDir() {
            paths <- path
        }
        return nil
    }); err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Errorf("failed Walk: %w", err))
    }
}

func worker(paths <-chan string, wg *sync.WaitGroup, client *putio.Client) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for path := range paths {
        f, err := os.Open(path)
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf(Red + "Failed to open file %v for reading" + Reset, f.Name())
        }
        upload, err := client.Files.Upload(context.TODO(), f, path, 0)
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf(Red + "Failed to upload file %v" + Reset, upload.File.Name)
        }
        log.Printf(Green+ "File %v has been uploaded succesfully" + Reset, upload.File.Name)
    }
}
```

I did write the code. That's the cleanest I can do and I was told to write a unit test for the program. I'm confused. For example, considering the `WalkFilePath` function. What should I provide and what kind of result I should expect to test the function. Because it contains `channel` communication meaning `goroutines`. Is there any way to write unit tests for this program clearly? Or should I change the code structure which is not good in this case for me. Btw, the program runs properly.

Comment: "Btw, the program runs properly." that program doesn't .  You refer to undefined variables in `WalkFilePath`.

Comment: I didn't put the unnecessary code. that's why.

Answer (score 1):

Like most things, Go is very opinionated about how to test. Make sure to read https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/add-a-test

> For example, considering the WalkFilePath function. What should I provide and what kind of result I should expect to test the function.

The input to `WalkFilePath` *should* be `paths` and a `rootpath`.  Your `WalkFilePath` doesn't get `paths` or `rootpath` from anywhere, so this code wouldn't compile as is (testing will help catch that stuff of course).

A test for `WalkFilePath` might be done something like this:

1. Create a filesystem structure in your project under `testdata/`, a directory [expressly set aside for data used for testing](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go/internal/test).   Create subdirectories and files.  For an example that might look like:

   ```
   testdata/
      walktest/
         dir1/
            file1.txt
         dir2/
             file2.txt
             dir3/
                file3.txt
   ```
2. Now you can define the expected data you'll be getting out of your channel.

   ```
   expected_paths := []string{
      "testdata/walktest/dir1/file1.txt",
      "testdata/walktest/dir2/file2.txt",
      "testdata/walktest/dir3/file3.txt"
   }
   ```
3. Now you need to change `WalkFilePath` to take arguments for `rootpath` and `paths`.

   ```
   func WalkFilePath(rootdir string, paths chan<- string) {
   ```
4. Now you're ready to write your test.

   ```
   func TestWalkFilePath(t *testing.T(
      paths := make(chan string)
      go WalkFilePath("testdata/walktest")
      results := make([]string,0)
      for path := range paths {
        results = append(results, path)
      }
      exp, res := strings.Join(expected_paths, ""), strings.Join(results, "")
      if exp != res {
        t.Errorf("Expected %s got %s", exp, res)
      }
   }
   ```

> Because it contains channel communication meaning goroutines.

It's totally normal and valid to use channels and goroutines in unit tests.